# how to do random caps (python)

Tags: python

Hey so I have a project where we have to make a random password generator and I need to have a caps in it somewhere. So I have like the ceaser cipher and I need it to have random caps somewhere. can someone help plss

edit : ok so basically you need the person to input the website they need the password for which is why i was like lets do ceaser cipher so they can input the website then we alter the wesbite name from there n from the cipher we can just have random letters in the ciper get capitalized yk

this is my code so far (after the random caps part i plan to ask for their fav num then add it with a symbol & then print their password)

```
def caesar_encryption(plaintext,key):
  encryption_str = ''
  for i in plaintext:
    if i.isupper():
      temp = 65 + ((ord(i) - 65 + key) % 26) 
      encryption_str = encryption_str + chr(temp)                              
    elif i.islower():
      temp = 97 + ((ord(i) - 97 + key) % 26)
      encryption_str = encryption_str + chr(temp)
    else:
      encryption_str = encryption_str + i  

  print("The ciphertext is:",encryption_str)
 
plaintext = input("Enter the Website Name:")
key = int(input("Enter the key:"))
caesar_encryption(plaintext,key)
```

Comment: Why are you using a caesar cipher? Just go over every letter, randomly changing it to a capital letter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand the question. Please read [ask] - "can someone help pls" is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). What steps do you imagine are needed in order to solve the problem? What part don't you know how to do? For example, do you know how to do **anything** "random" in Python? What exactly is a "random cap"? You mean that a specific letter should, according to a random *decision*, be either uppercase or lowercase, yes? In other words, you want to make a random *choice* between those two possibilities?

Comment: You're not supposed to edit your question to add "thanks" or "solved". This website is creating a database of useful questions and answers that could be useful for others in the future. If you think an answer is good, you can upvote it and/or mark it as accepted. The question should remain as it was (and obviously may be improved to make clarifications or improve grammar and formatting).

Answer (score 1):

No need for a caesar cipher. Just loop over every character, changing it randomly to a capital letter. Like this:

```
import random

def random_caps(string):
    newstring = ""
    for ch in string:
        if ch.isalpha() and random.randint(0, 1):
            newstring += ch.upper()
        else:
            newstring += ch
    return newstring
```

You could also use a list comprehension like this:

```
import random

def random_caps(string):
    return ''.join([ch.upper() if random.randint(0, 1) else ch for ch in string])
```

Answer (score -1):

i had to do that to here is what i did

```
import random
    
letters = ["A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c"] #and so on
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"] #and so on
special_characters = ["/", "!", "@"] #and so on
    
def password():
    n1 = random.choice(letters) #or any others
    n2 = random.choice(numbers) #or any others
    n3 = random.choice(letters) #or any others
    n4 = random.choice(special_characters) #or any others
    n5 = random.choice(numbers) #or any others
    n6 = random.choice(letters) #or any others
    n7 = random.choice(special_characters) #or any others
    n8 = random.choice(letters) #or any others
    password = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8
    print(password)
password()
```

Comment: There is no guarantee with this strategy that the password will contain any uppercase letters

Comment: yes but 6/10 times there is caps

Comment: And 4/10 there will not be any caps. So it doesn't fulfil the brief

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).